# EF CodeFirst One-to-One

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

I find thousands examples for codefirst relations, but i can't do work my sample !

Many errors like this:

The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'LanguageID' on type 'BL.Objects.User' is not valid. The navigation property 'Language' was not found on the dependent type 'BL.Objects.User'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

and same same same...

I really want to load language association with user. (en, ru, es)

```
public abstract class BaseUser : FinanceBase<int>, IUser
{      
    [ForeignKey("Language")]
    public int LanguageID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LanguageID")]
    public virtual Language Language { get; private set; }        

}

public class User : BaseUser
{
    public override void GenerateID()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public abstract class BaseLanguage : FinanceBase<int>, ILanguage
{
    #region Implementation of ILanguage

    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class Language : BaseLanguage
{
    public override void GenerateID()
    {

    }
}

public class FinanceDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public FinanceDatabaseContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new FinanceContextInitializer());    
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
                m.ToTable("Users");
            }).HasKey(x => x.ID).HasRequired(x => x.Language).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.LanguageID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Language>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Languages");
        }).HasKey(x => x.ID);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    } 
}

public class FinanceContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<FinanceDatabaseContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(FinanceDatabaseContext context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE Users ADD CONSTRAINT uc_Language UNIQUE(LanguageID)");
    }
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use foreign key for `LanguageID`

```
    public int LanguageID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LanguageID ")]
    public virtual Language Language { get; private set; }
```

Comment: I did it ! But now error is: The navigation property 'Language' is not a declared property on type 'User'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid navigation property.

Answer (score 0):

Add a virtual navigation field to your User table for language if it isnt already there.
Ie you have LanguageId and Language in the POCO class User.
The alternative is a navigation field in Language Class back to User,
ie Public virtual List Users

But lets stick to Users having BOTH **virtual navigation property and Foreign Key Id field.**

```
 ... the rest of User.....
    public int LanguageId
// nav relationship
    public virtual Language Language { set; get; }

// Now the FK declaration as you described should work in fluent API...
// Has required NAVIGATION property, its 1 to many and the I have a field for this FK value called X

modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties();
            m.ToTable("Users");
        }).HasKey(x => x.ID).HasRequired(x => x.Language).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.LanguageID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. My Navigation property Language has **private** setter

```
[ForeignKey("LanguageID")]
public virtual Language Language { get; private set; }
```